# No module named 'django.urls'

Tags: django

I have a problem:

```
ImportError at /  No module named 'django.urls'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from polls.views import *
urlpatterns = [
    path('', EnterPage, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('main/',EnterPage),
    path('login/',loginn),
    path('admin-panel/',adminPan),
    path('control-users/',panel),
    path('menu/',menu),
    path('perspage/',lk),
    path('spisok-zakazov/',product),
    path('info/',info),
    path('task-panel/', tasks),
    path('tasks/',earncoin)
]
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Comment: Are you sure Django is installed at all? Or maybe you have used django as your own package name somewhere?

Comment: Make sure there's no directory called `django` in your project. That will mess with python's import order.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're using an older django version. You can check your version using:

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

If you look at the django documentation there are several modifications including the urls module.

Version >= 2.0: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/

```
from django.urls import include, path
```

Version < 2.0: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
```

Django 2.0 release notes:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax